# How to loop through each and every row, put value in gridview column cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have gridview with 3 columns and 100 rows. and one submit button out of gridview.

here first 2 column is bounded field and 3rd one is Label (templatefield) .

Now, I want to change status of 3rd column and display it to gridview when loop run.

**i want to**

```
when i=0 then i want to change label's value to "SUCESS" and display on Gridview,
     i=1 then i want to change label's value to "SUCESS" and display on Gridview,
     and so on till i=100.
```

**Gridview**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvCategoryLive" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No Records Found !"  >
  <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitName" HeaderText="Unit Name" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CreateDate" HeaderText="Created Date" />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="UnitMesurement_Id" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**I am trying something like this**

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnSave.Text == "Save")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GvCategoryLive.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(9000);
            GvCategoryLive.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text = "Success";

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is happening or not happening with the code you have currently?

Comment: Websites do not work that way. Only when the code has finished is an updated page send to the client with all cells having "Success". You can only do this with Ajax.

Comment: @VDWWD how can do this ajax?

Comment: That's hard to implement in asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

I really dont remember the gridviews and asp.net webforms but

You may use setTimeout in javascript

```
var rowCount = 100;// get row count here
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++)
{
   setTimeout($('#cell'+i).html('Success'), 9000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnSave.Text == "Save")
    {
        foreach(GridViewRow row in GvCategoryLive.Rows) {
                if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
                    Label UnitMesurement_Id= row.FindControl("UnitMesurement_Id") as Label ;
                    UnitMesurement_Id.Text = "Success";
                }
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not setting the value of a cell but label inside that cell, you should change this-

```
GvCategoryLive.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text = "Success";
```

into-

```
Label UnitMesurement_Id = GvCategoryLive.Rows[i].FindControl("UnitMesurement_Id") as Label;
UnitMesurement_Id.Text = "Success";
```